# Error in syntax java netbeans 7 in project inventory item

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7

I have an error in java code,
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String "

Comment: It clearly states that there is a syntax error in SQL. Without showing us code we cannot help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373752/java-awt-eventqueue-0-error
Handle when the value in string is null! (Error beacuse of null value in string)

Comment: I could send the code themselves before, but something goes wrong on the delivery because of past comments that a maximum limit of 150 characters .. so i need how to display the code.?
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be numerous reasons that can cause this exception. Code snippet will be more helpful to detect the cause.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/rar/zn4q8hnr/AplikasiPenjualan.html